# Ruby if else statement refactoring

Tags: ruby, refactoring

The current code works:

```
def launched_city(country, city, city_link)
  return 'current' if country == 'Malaysia' && ('Kuala Lumpur' == city_link)
  return 'current' if country == 'Philippines' && ('Manila' == city_link)
  if country == 'Australia'
    return 'current' if city == 'Melbourne' && ('Melbourne' == city_link)
    return 'current' if city == 'Sydney' && ('Sydney' == city_link)
    return 'current' if city == 'Perth' && ('Perth' == city_link)
  end
  nil
end
```

but I think it's ugly. Any help?

I tried with `case` block. It failed with the `case` statement because I need to check the second statement. I also tried with `if elsif else` block. It's the same in this case.

Comment: `session` is a method? Please show it. If it's a variable you need it as an argument of the method (`def launched_city(city_link, session)`).

Comment: its from rails, let me update again the code to be ruby specific

Comment: @CarySwoveland updated to be more ruby specific

Answer (score 2):

```
COUNTRY_LINKS = { 'Malaysia'=>['Kuala Lumpur'],
                  'Philippines'=>['Manila'],
                  'Australia'=>['Melbourne', 'Sydney', 'Perth'] }

def launched_city(country, city, city_link)
  if COUNTRY_LINKS.has_key?(country) && COUNTRY_LINKS[country].include? city_link) &&
    (country != 'Australia' || city == city_link)
    'current'
  end
end
```

Comment: I like your use of hash, but I would have `city_link` as the key and `country` as the value.

Comment: I don't think it is clean to explicitly return `nil`. I would use postfix `if` instead of ternary and let `nil` be returned by default.

Comment: @sawa, what if the city were Rome? The one in Italy or one of the 13 in the US? Edited to fix city and incorporate your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: I don't get how you got my comment; now you are missing `city_link`. And what is Rome in US?

Comment: @sawa, have you ever wished you had just skipped over a question that you had answered? I thought you meant you wanted the hash to have cities as keys and countries as values. I was just pointing out that cities are not unique. Maybe that's not what you meant.

Comment: `city == city_link` is only for `'Australia'`. But I don't care about this question.